# Integrate Bootstrap theme into October CMS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, octobercms

I have a basic page setup using October CMS and I need to integrate AdminLTE theme into it. I have done this previously in Laravel but not sure how to do it in October CMS. Can someone help?

Comment: you have to build a new theme. see documentation here https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/themes

Comment: @Pierre-AndréVullioud Do you mean port it to October CMS as a theme and then use it?

Comment: yes, you can create a custom theme based on AdminLTE

Comment: @Pierre-AndréVullioud if I can create a custom theme based on AdminLTE, then can I release it as a paid theme in October CMS? I ask this since AdminLTE is free and open source.

Comment: I have no idea about the legal contraints of AdminLTE

Comment: Could you make an answer so I can do accept the answer and close this discussion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to build a new theme. see documentation here octobercms.com/docs/cms/themes

Building a theme from a template is really easy with octobercms.